# how does member declaration with assignment relate to ctors?

Tags: c++11, constructor

Sorry - I'm sure I'm just not finding any answers because I don't know the nomenclature!

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() { }   // default ctor
  explicit Foo(int a) : _a(a) { }   // semi-explicit - but what is _b's value??
protected:
  int _a = 9;  // HOW DOES THIS RELATE TO EACH OF THE CTORS?!
  int _b = 3;  // HOW DOES THIS RELATE TO EACH OF THE CTORS?!
};
```

By explicitly specifying a default ctor w/o specifying _a or _b, do the declared assignments happen (_a = 9, _b = 3) or do those only happen if I *don't* create a default ctor (or I declare as Foo() = default;)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 [class.base.init]/8:

> In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member or base class is not designated by a *mem-initializer-id* (including the case where there is no *mem-initializer-list* because the constructor has no *ctor-initializer*) and the entity is not a virtual base class of an abstract class (10.4), then
>
> — if the entity is a non-static data member that has a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, the entity is initialized as specified in 8.5;
>
> — ...

So, in your case, a default-initialized `Foo` has `_a == 9` and `_b == 3` since neither `_a` or `_b` appear in the (absent) *mem-initializer-list*. `Foo(7)` will have `_a == 7` and `_b == 3`, since `_b` does not appear in the *mem-initializer-list*.

Comment: So, basically, unless there is an explicit initialization in the member initializer list, then the given brace-or-equal-initializer is used?  That sounds like what I would want in the best of all worlds, thanks.

Comment: @Mordachai Yes, that's it exactly.